# Should I upsize my PEX plumbing when adding a bathroom?

Tags: plumbing, pex

I'm in the process of adding 1 more full bathroom and a bar to my house. As I've been researching how to go about, I've stumbled upon this [resource](https://up.codes/viewer/portland/upc-2021/chapter/6/water-supply-and-distribution#610.4) for sizing the PEX pipes.

It says my current setup is grossly undersized (recommend size is 1 1/4" for 38 fixture units!) and I'm a bit conflicted. I had my house re-piped 1 year ago with PEX, and the plumber at the time re-piped with 3/4" PEX as main branch with city line at 3/4". I've informed him that I would be adding a basement bathroom and bar at a later date so he takes that into account and he acknowledged. I already had 2 full baths and 1 half bath.

So the question is, should I upsize my PEX as per the code? I have been experiencing drop in flow when

- washing machine is on and 1 shower is on
- 1 shower on and tub spout on (tub spout is decades old so might not have flow limiter)

The drop is not intolerable, and actually 2 shower on is fine. But looking into the future when I'll have 1 more full bath and a bar sink, I'm wondering whether I should take the opportunity to upsize my PEX to 1" at least when I have the ceiling exposed.

I also wanted to gather some info on what size people typically have for their main branch and their experience. is 3/4" main branch ok for 3.5 baths + washing machine + 1.5 kitchens? Is that code that I'm looking at realistic or just theoretical? Are the drop in flow expected in above scenarios? I haven't lived in a detached house for over a decade so can't remember whether that was normal or not.

Comment: also adding the pressure going into the main branch is around 56 PSI (reduced by pressure regulator)

Comment: I don't know that I've ever _not_ experienced a pressure/flow drop when the washing machine kicks on, or a toilet flushes or other major water consumer kicks in. Not in any house I've ever been in.

Comment: hmm I see. Do you mind me asking what size pipes do you have in your house?

Comment: I believe we've got 1/2" supply lines. However, this has been true of every house I've lived in, and don't have the foggiest idea what size plumbing was in them all.

Comment: 1/2 inch piping usually only good to turn on one tap at a time for full pressure/flow.  Larger pipe sizes are better if more taps are wanted to be on at the same time.  Greater flow.  Think newer houses are going with the 3/4 size now.

Comment: Doesn't PEX use fittings that constrict the ID of the pipe at the joint?

Comment: To get objective technical answers you need to better define the question, namely 1) Are you contemplating digging up your yard and putting in a new supply line from the street, and if so what options are available to you? 2) What is your goal?  For example, "With one shower in use, a toilet flushed in a different bathroom should not reduce pressure more than 20%", or for another example, "3 showers, 2 toilets and the washing machine can run together with no more than 2% loss in pressure or flow at any of them."  I mean that would be ridiculous, but you must define "Should I ....."

Comment: Find out the nominal size of your water meter. Should be on your bill. In Dallas TX the possibilities for a residence are 5/8", 3/4", 1", 1.5",  2", 3", 4". We have a 5/8" and it works OK for our 4-bdrm 2-bath 2000 sq ft house, but maybe a larger meter would improve your maximum flow. I would not think you would need more than a 1". The city of Dallas will change the meter at no installation charge AFIK and there would presumably be a fixed monthly charge on your bill which is dependent on the meter size.. You might need a larger supply line from the meter to your house. This would be $$$$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a plumber but it would seem like your main constraint is the feed to the house.  3/4" is pretty small.  Did you say you had 38 fixture units? ???  That must be a huge house. At any rate, it all depends upon what is used concurrently.

Given the feed is only 3/4" increasing internal piping to 1" or 1 1/4" won't buy you much unless you replace the underground feed to the house. And who knows what the feed to the meter is (assuming on muni water). Not only that if you increase to 1" or 1 1/4" it will take ***FOREVER*** for fixtures to get HW in fixtures that are far away from the WH, unless you have HW recirc installed.

There are a few hacks that can be done:  Install a large storage tank, controlled by float valves (for fill level) then to a pressure pump to a pressure tank with appropriate controls, then to the house. A garage is a good place to install this equipment, the large storage tank can go outside.  But it's complicated enough you really need a pro plumber who is familiar with water supply systems, pump, tanks, controls, etc .   If you are on a well, well(no joke intended!) everything changes.

Comment: yea it's unfortunate. House is 30+ years old so maybe that's why. I might have added the fixture units wrong, but with 3.5 bath, 1.5 kitchen, washing machine that's what I got.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 1.5" poly ethylene service.  I branch that into 3x 1" copper manifolds.  These manifolds then branch out for a 3 level house with two kitchens.

I have several 1/2" homerun cold water lines to sinks where I want cold water for drinking fast.  You need to dump all the existing water in lines to get to ground temp water.  My city water is excellent for drinking.

The hotwater pipes I homerun almost all of them from a hotwater manifold near a hot water tank.  To get hot water as quick as possible, you have to dump all the water in the line.

I do have some 1/2" hot water pex lines that serve a couple fixtures, generally I'll take the 1/2" line to the kitchen sink hot and then tee to a dishwasher so you can dump the existing water and get the dishwasher water hot.  I also generally do the same for sink / shower ( you typically use one at a time and you'll charge the line if you use either one and then the other ).

I run 3/4" cold as a branch to things I don't care about like toilet, laundry, exterior hose bibs.

Since the pex fittings are interal fittings 3/4" pex will be more restrictive generally than 3/4" copper.  I'd upsize to 1" pex in your case but possibly run some parallel 1/2" lines and home run some hot water.

Comment: _"Since the pex fittings are interal fittings 3/4" pex will be more restrictive generally than 3/4" copper."_ This is not true for f1960 expansion fittings which is relatively popular.

Comment: Yeah you can use expansion Pex-A that has the extra plastizers and expose yourself to more chemical leach risk but get increased flow.  I'll stick to pex B and just upsize if I am worried about flow.

Comment: Regardless, many PEX B providers are supporting f1960 cold expansion too. So that comment seems kind of tangential.

Comment: Oh I didn't know there was a pex b expansion option, the pex b pipe will expand with the expander and the pex b pipe manufacturers support it?  I'll have to do some more research.  Thanks !

Comment: I'm 100% Zurn does it now, and a few others too. Be careful though because these ecosystems for PEX B are hella-lock in. They require a special expansion fitting, and all manufacturer created f1960 adapters to keep warranty.